# sth wrong with .searchable

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have added `searchable` to my SwiftUI List.
But the search TextField isn't showing.

Here is my code:

```
NavigationView {
    List(searchResults, id: \.self) { item in
        NavigationLink {
            LegendDetailView(item: item)
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text(item.name).padding(1)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right").imageScale(.small)
            }
        }
    }
}.searchable(text: $searchText)
```

**EDIT(2021/5/29):**
I thinks there is a piece of important infomation I forgot to say
*This view is a popover*

Answer (score 4):

> I add searchable to my SwiftUI List

No, you *added* it to the navigation view. Move it up

```
NavigationView {
    List(searchResults, id: \.self) { item in
        NavigationLink {
            LegendDetailView(item: item)
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text(item.name).padding(1)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right").imageScale(.small)
            }
        }
    }.searchable(text: $searchText)
}
```

Text example

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var letters = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon", "zeta"]
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        let searchResults = searchText.isEmpty ? letters : letters.filter{$0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)}
        NavigationView {
            List(searchResults, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink {
                    Text(item)
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text(item).padding(1)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }.searchable(text: $searchText)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I came up with and it won't work so I moved it down to the `NavigationView`

Comment: I just tested the code. It does work.

Comment: ???why mine won't???